# Issue with If Clause in php

Tags: php, if-statement, whitespace

I am very new to this site and this is my first question. I want to display different submission forms on the basis of input being sent via form. Please have a look at the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $camp = $_POST['camp'];

    if($camp == "Final Expense"){
        echo "FE Form Goes Here";
    }
    if($camp == "Home Improvements"){
        echo "HI Form Goes Here";
    }
?>
```

Now since there is space between Home Improvements and also between Final Expense Word, therefore it is always false. If I remove the space from input and remove space from here e.g Home_Improvements and Final_Expense then it works.

How Can I maintain the input with spaces and the tests here with spaces too. Please answer anybody. Thanks..

Comment: the space shouldn't be an issue; post the form for this

Comment: One solution would be to keep your different forms that you want to display in include files and simply call the includes modules based on the conditional statements.

Comment: What values are actually being posted for `$camp`? If the value doesn't match exactly, then it will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Jorden1337 thanks for the suggestion but the problem is that I can't make the condition true since there is space between Home and Improvements words and that is stopping the condition from coming true.

Comment: Your code will still work with spaces. But it is case sensitive, so check your inputs. Also, check to see if your inputs have any extra spaces or line endings at the end, they will evaluate to false if you == them to a string without those extra spaces.

Comment: Kindly do `var_dump($camp);` before the second `if` and let us know what you got

Comment: if you won't update your post, then that's up to you. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blanks shouldn't be problem.

Be sure that you have post the whole words. You could check this by echoing the field you posted.

To avoid posting incomplete words, please add quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you so much, your comments were so much useful. I echoed the incoming variable and it was sending the name incomplete. It was because of this echo "<option value=$rs[0]>$rs[0]</option>"; Now I enclosed the value in single quotation marks and it is like echo "<option value='$rs[0]'>$rs[0]</option>"; This works fine for me now. Thank you so much..

Answer (score -2):

Well this worked for me just fine.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["camp"])){
    $camp = $_POST['camp'];
    if (stripos($camp, "Final") > -1 && stripos($camp, "Expense") > -1) {
        echo "FE Form Goes Here";
    }
    if(stripos($camp, "Home") > -1 && stripos($camp, "Improvements") > -1){
        echo "HI Form Goes Here";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No sir, it's still the same, it wants the white space be removed from the value of incoming variable i.e. $_POST['camp']

Comment: The issue with OP is going to be related to the value of $camp. Adding the request method does not fix this.

Comment: I tried `Final Expense` and it worked, then I tried `Final` this, which didn't work(as expected).

Comment: Ok I made it in the simplest form. Without complicated preg_match

Comment: Still helpless.... The space between two inputs is not being accepted....

Comment: That shouldn't happen as this logic look for two words to exist on the input, it doesn't care about what case they are or if there are any other words in the input. Could you double check the logic to see if you missed anything. I did test this with http://phpfiddle.org